# MSP 430FR5739 interfacing with Adafuit ultimate gps

Tags: gps, uart, msp430, interfacing

i am doing a low power mode gps project for **msp430fr5739** development board. this board's operating voltage is 3.3 volts and my **gps** module also can operate with 3.3 volts supplied power. How about effect of logic levels of UART protocol. do i have to use a *logic level* converter between gps module and msp430 ? or can i directly plug and play Adafuit gps ultimate board with msp430fr5739 development board

Comment: This question belongs on [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I agree with @CL., but to "short circuit" the matter why not just measure the output voltage of the pins on the gps module that you are interested in? You will need an oscilloscope. It is unlikely they will be higher than 3.3v.

Comment: thanks i put this question on stack exchange electrical and i found the answer.